# Possible to change Gitlab repository creation schema?

Tags: git, gitlab

My Gitlab repos path is set to :

```
data/git/repositories
```

if now a user called Superman creates a new project gitlab will automatically setup the git repos path to :

```
data/git/repositories/Superman/Projectname
```

Does anyone know where I can configure that ? I don't want to have the owners name in my repos path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do want the user's name in the repository's path, set up a group for a project, and work against that group's repository/ies. Then repositories will lay in:

```
/path/repositories/projectgroup/projectname
```

Thoug, gitlab somehow works like github, where each user has its own personal repositories, where he can sync all his development branches and make merge requests to the group's repositories with its sets of commits, so it's easier to track modifications' ownership through forks.

Have a look at a [tutorial such as this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-the-gitlab-user-interface-to-manage-projects) for how to create and use it.

Comment: the folder is created when the group is created, yes. So you suggest to simply copy the "git" files into that folder? out of the superman folder? and than work against that group folder? Thank you

Comment: well, if your project already exists for user `Superman`, simply make a `fork` of that project into the group you're creating for the project.

Comment: I just created a special user and let him create the project so the path looks better for all :) and no workarounds needed